# Choosing a sleeping pad for camping

Tags: camping, backpacking, sleeping-pads

I currently own the most basic closed cell sleeping pad that one could buy. I'd like to upgrade to a better self  inflating pad. I've narrowed it down to about two options:
[REI AirRail 1.5](http://www.rei.com/product/845298/rei-airrail-15-self-inflating-sleeping-pad)
[REI Trekker](http://www.rei.com/product/870759/rei-trekker-self-inflating-sleeping-pad)

The first has a higher r-value, is cheaper, and is flat which may be nice when sleeping with another person. However, it's about twice as large as it doesn't fold when wrapping up. Now I'd like to take this on car camps, bike tours, and backpacking. It shouldn't be a problem on my bike as my previous pad is about the same size.

But when backpacking, would there be a significant disadvantage to taking the larger pad? I assume it would have to go on the outside of the pack. Would the smaller one reasonably fit in a pack? It's a pound heavier but I don't plan on going on week long hikes just yet. Is this just a question of whether I would prefer the comfort of a nice pad or the comfort of less clunky gear?

Comment: I can't see how this is answerable as it stands. It's purely down to preference and also the size of your bag

Comment: Do you have a mummy style sleeping bag?

Comment: @Paarazzi: Mine is mummy style. My friend I'll be buying for as well has a rectangular one to use in the cold but most of the time will be using a cheap mummy style not rated for the cold

Comment: @Liam:  I guess part of my question is whether it is answerable. I'm trying to figure out if there is a definitive way I should go about making this decision. If that's not specific enough for this then I can try to edit the post or look elsewhere for some general advice

Comment: While both should be considered backpacker style camping, the AirRail is quite a bit more comfortable.

Comment: This is a personal preference question, I for example carry more bedding than most because I like to sleep more comfortably.

Comment: both are amazingly heavy for backpacking. Also both would be considered winter pads with regard to their insulation level. I would not hesitate a second and take neither.

Comment: I don't see this as problematic due to being opinion based - almost all gear related choices involve a degree of opinion. Still we had many such questions which provided useful information about "why" (as njzk2's answer here shows as well). I think that the question would improve if the question is made clearer (e.g. which one is more suitable for tasks x, y, z?).

Comment: Everyone, please see this:  http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/587/possible-shopping-question-where-can-i-get-gear-like-this/588#588.  Asking "would there be a significant disadvantage to taking the larger pad?" is not opinion based.  There are distinct disadvantages of larger/heavier pads and this can be answered.  The merits of one pad over another is not strictly an opinion based question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the characteristics of the pads you selected, here is what I can say:

### Weight

Crucial when backpacking.

- 1lbs 1oz (740g) is on the heavy side, but still doable.
- 2.5 lbs (1140g) is enormous. If you put that on the outside of your pack, it could unbalance it, and pull you backward. Unless you put it at the bottom, but then you risk tearing your pad when you put your pack down.

### Packing size

- 6.5 x 9 inches is ~10L, which fits in a pack.
- 4.75 x 21.25 inches is ~12.5L. Not much more, pretty thin so you can possible put it in the pack, but the length may be an inconvenience to fill your pack.

### R-value

Both are winter-capable values, depending on what the winter looks like where you are.

- 4.2. Should be good down to -10C (15F)
- 5.6. Should be good down to -20C (0F)

### Comfort

.25" (6.3mm) may make a difference, but that part is very subjective. I find 1.5" (38mm) to be plenty. The shape depends on how you sleep.

### Conclusion

If I *had* to choose within these 2, I would not hesitate and take the AirRail 1.5. But it is still too heavy for backpacking for me, so I would probably not take it anyway, unless I needed the R-value for cold weather.

Comment: I disagree on "quite heavy for backpacking".  1lb 11oz for a pad is on the heavier side, but is only "quite heavy" if you are trying to go ultralight.  (+1 all the same for a informative answer).

Comment: @RussellSteen agreed, some people may find it light enought, and an inflatable of 1.5" for that weight is not surprising, especially given the high R-value

Answer (score 1):

For 1lbs 1oz (740g) I'd choose an inflatable pad.  Mine is 72"x20"x2.5" and super comfortable.  It's also warm because your body is not in contact with the ground.  It takes a few minutes to inflate by mouth (it's an "air core", no foam inside) but well worth the time.